# C++ Database get array of rows from a table using SQL ODBC

Tags: c++, sql, database, ms-access, odbc

Refering to this link [C++\SQL ODBC: Get row from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179779/c-sql-odbc-get-row-from-table)
I don't understand the docs and have tried many variations to get something to work but it just outputs complete jibberish. Basically, how can I get data from my Microsoft Access Database into my C++ program. I would eventually want to get the entire table stored as arrays or vectors, that being, lets say there are 5 fields in my table, I want to store (in 5 different arrays or vectors) all the contents to the corresponding fields. But for now, how can I just have something like a table called "Example Table" and within it it has 1 field called "Names" and the type is a string or "short text" as Access calls it. How can I then load that into an array of strings or char*'s to use for my GUI or other parts of the program? Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <iostream>

WCHAR szDSN[] = L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\databaseExample\\databaseExample\\Data.accdb";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HENV    hEnv;
    HDBC    hDbc;

    /* ODBC API return status */
    RETCODE rc;

    int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
    WCHAR    szConnStrOut[256];

    const WCHAR* query = L"select Names from Example_Table";

    HSTMT           hStmt;

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    /* Connect to the database */
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN,
        SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut,
        255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {

        wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n",
            szConnStrOut);

        /* Prepare SQL query */
        wprintf(L"SQL query:\n  %s\n", query);

        rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)query, SQL_NTS);

        /* Excecute the query */
        rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
        {
            wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n", szDSN);
    }

    /* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    getchar();
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [SQLGetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function?view=sql-server-ver15), passing SQL_C_WCHAR type, for example, if your column is text. Here's example how to get values of the single text column and put them to vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

WCHAR szDSN[] = L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Test\\users.accdb";

void DisplayError(SQLSMALLINT t, SQLHSTMT h) {
    SQLWCHAR       SqlState[6], Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SQLINTEGER    NativeError;
    SQLSMALLINT   i, MsgLen;
    SQLRETURN     rc;

    SQLLEN numRecs = 0;
    SQLGetDiagField(t, h, 0, SQL_DIAG_NUMBER, &numRecs, 0, 0);

    // Get the status records.
    i = 1;
    while (i <= numRecs && (rc = SQLGetDiagRec(t, h, i, SqlState, &NativeError,
        Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {
        wprintf(L"Error %d: %s\n", NativeError, Msg);
        i++;
    }

}

std::vector<std::wstring> ExecuteSql(const WCHAR* sql) {

    std::vector<std::wstring> results = {};
    HENV    hEnv = NULL;
    HDBC    hDbc = NULL;
    HSTMT hStmt = NULL;
    int iConnStrLength2Ptr;
    WCHAR szConnStrOut[256];
    SQLINTEGER rowCount = 0;
    SQLSMALLINT fieldCount = 0;
    SQLWCHAR buf[128];
    SQLINTEGER ret;

    /* ODBC API return status */
    RETCODE rc;

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    /* Connect to the database */
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN,
        SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut,
        255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {
        /* Prepare SQL query */
        rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)sql, SQL_NTS);

        /* Excecute the query */
        rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
        {
            SQLNumResultCols(hStmt, &fieldCount);

            if (fieldCount > 0)
            {
                /* Loop through the rows in the result set */

                rc = SQLFetch(hStmt);

                while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
                {                   
                    //get data
                    rc = SQLGetData(hStmt, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, buf, sizeof(buf), &ret);
                    
                    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc) == FALSE) {
                        wprintf(L"SQLGetData failed\n");
                        continue;
                    }

                    //convert data to string
                    std::wstring str;
                    if (ret <= 0) {
                        str = std::wstring(L"(null");
                    }
                    else {
                        str = std::wstring(buf);
                    }
                    
                    results.push_back(str);
                    rc = SQLFetch(hStmt);
                    rowCount++;
                };

                rc = SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_DROP);

            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"Error: Number of fields in the result set is 0.\n");
            }

        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
            DisplayError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s\n", szDSN);
        DisplayError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    }

    /* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
    return results;
}

int main()
{
    auto results = ExecuteSql(L"SELECT name FROM Users");

    for (auto x : results) {
        std::wcout << x << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow I can't even thank you enough! That saved me big time I was getting in real deep with C++/CLI as a solution but it kept limiting me with specific includes not available that are in native C++, thank you so much!!